# Cannot find -lSDLmain and -lSDL when compiling simple SDL program with g++

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl-2

I installed SDL2 for mingw using [this](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/mingw/index.php) guide. However, when i try to compile using the compilation syntax and test code they provide, only with my own file names, I get the error shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6fwetjvveihlyb/mingw_sdl_error.png?dl=0). I assume that this error has something to do with a problem in the way I installed SDL, as the installation instructions did not exactly match the files with which I was provided, but I did my best to follow them. Could they problem be something else? If not what is the correct way to install SDL2 for mingw?

Note: I **do** have the SDL2.dll file in the sdltest folder where I try to compile the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to let MinGW know where your SDL libraries are would be to create environment variable named "LIBRARY_PATH" with the value as the path to the directory containing the libraries. Similarly, you can have "CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH" for the headers as well.

Did you follow step 2 of that tutorial ?