# Error in Code::Blocks when building and running any source file/project. (ld.exe cannot find -lSDLmain)

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

Build messages:

ld.exe  cannot find -lSDLmain
ld.exe  cannot find -lSDL

Build log:

c:/program files
(x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lSDLmain

c:/program files
(x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lSDL

Please help.
Its not letting me run any of my previous or new projects.(All console applications/projects)

- I have checked
  *settings* - *global* *variables*
  the *include* and *lib* paths are correct as well as the *base* *directory*.
- I recently tried to setup `SDL2` but then I uninstalled Code::blocks completely.
  Why is it trying to find *-lSDLmain* and -lSDL?
- Also tried reinstalling code::blocks and the *Rebuild* other than just *Build*, still
  does not work.
- I checked this post:  [Cannot find -lSDLmain and -lSDL when compiling simple SDL program with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293572/cannot-find-lsdlmain-and-lsdl-when-compiling-simple-sdl-program-with-g)

  but the answer talks about letting your MinGW know where your SDL libraries are.
  But I'm not even working with SDL.
- Using GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: Did you create your project by way of `File->New->Project...->SDL Project`?

Comment: No, my previous projects are all console applications.  File->New->Project->Console application

Comment: Hmm, perhaps your projects have explicit references to SDLmain and SDL? Can you check the project settings, specifically `Project->Properties...->Libraries` to see if it lists anything SDL-related?

Comment: Both the left and right side areas are totally empty in `Project->Properties->Libraries`  There aren't any references to SDLmain or SDL inany of my previous projects.