# Missing -lSDL and -lSDLmain for SDL2

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl-2

I'm trying to compile a Code::Blocks project with SDL2, but the file won't build, with the errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in SDLtest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lSDLmain|
ld.exe||cannot find -lSDL|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I've followed everything correctly from [this tutorial for SDL2](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php), and the program that I'm using is the tutorial program at step 9 (so, [this one](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/01_hello_SDL.zip)).

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293572/cannot-find-lsdlmain-and-lsdl-when-compiling-simple-sdl-program-with-g), but I don't understand what the answer is trying to say (despite it being accepted), and I can't seem to find any other answers. An answer to the question or an explanation to the other question is appreciated.

Comment: I think you meant -lSDL2 (note the 2 at the end)

Comment: @xaxxon Nope, I mean -lSDL.

Comment: The tutorial you link to says: If you get an error where the linker complains it can't find -lSDL2 or -lSDL2main, it means you messed up this step.

Comment: @xaxxon I haven't messed up this step, so that's why I'm asking for an answer. I've done what the tutorial says exactly.

Comment: The tutorial says to use -lSDL2

Comment: @xaxxon I used -lSDL2 in the paste. I don't think you understand my question.

Comment: Your error message says: ld.exe||cannot find -lSDL  that means you have -lSDL somewhere instead of -lSDL2

Comment: No, I do not have -lSDL anywhere in my code. Please use the chat.

Comment: see the image right above this line in the tutorial: "If you get an error where the linker complains about a bunch of undefined references, it means you messed up this step."   You are almost certainly missing 2 '2's, but I don't know codeblocks.

Comment: @xaxxon This is what I typed (or copy-pasted) into "other linker options": `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`, which is what is required to be pasted. I'm doing what the tutorial says. This is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Then I don't know what's going on, but it's looking for libSDL not libSDL2 based on the error message you posted.   Do you have to regenerate the project or makefiles in codeblocks or something?   I've never used it.